# Dynamics crm use linq to display list of memberworks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to run a LINQ query within a website plugin with Dynamics CRM Hosted. I need to us LINQ to retrieve a list of all the currently registered Members as shown in the MemberWorks tab. But to be host I have no idea where to start.

Ive really jumped in at the deep end with this one to help out a friend, and I find that necessity and crushing time demands are the best way to challenge my brain and learn something new. So please if you van give me relevant pointer Id really appreciate it.

To clarify my LINQ knowledge is at beginner level and my knowledge of the hosted Dynamics CRM datastructure is at a similar level. So Ive not really tried anything as I simply don't know where to start at this stage. But hopefully some kind folk can give me direction and Ill see where that takes me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I sincerely think that Google can give you more examples than StackOverflow users can type in a few days.

Comment: @GertArnold Surely then that could be said of all questions posed. Thanks for your help, its been really constructive. :-)

Comment: @GertArnold Its also somewhat ironic that this question ranks No1 on google for the search i just in my attempts to find this wealth of knowledge you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [Hosk's blog](http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/crm-2011-getting-started-with-linq-in-crm-2011/) you will probably find your answer, if not you will have other questions to ask :)

It's quite hard to give an answer to a question this general so excuse me if it's a bit fuzzy and not exactly what you expected

Comment: Hi, not at all. thanks for pointing me in the correct general direction of the exit door. ;-)